# Why don't debug symbols from my xcframework appear in the crash stack trace?

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, crashlytics, xcframework

I can't see debug symbols from my xcframework in crash reports. They just appear as memory addresses, as shown in the screenshot below.

The framework is built by my team, and integrated with Cocoapods into my employer's apps.

How do I get debug symbols to show up in the crash reports?

[image: stack trace of app crash]